# What does "pts/6" or "?" mean in the output of ps

Tags: 12.04, server, ps

I am running bitcoin, litecoin, dogecoin, auroracoin and anon coin servers in different ports. When I grep each coin has different configurations as shown below. I can't understand what the question mark is and what is pts. Followed something [here](https://litecointalk.org/index.php?topic=43.0). Have I configured correctly??

```
$ ps -ef | grep bitcoin
1001     18662 18279  2 17:34 pts/6    00:00:02 bitcoind
1001     18751 18279  0 17:35 pts/6    00:00:00 grep bit
$ ps -ef | grep lite
1001     18712 18279  2 17:35 pts/6    00:00:01 ./litecoin-d/src/litecoind
1001     18754 18279  0 17:36 pts/6    00:00:00 grep lite
$ ps -ef | grep doge
1001     18719     1  6 17:35 ?        00:00:03 ./dogecoin-d/src/dogecoind
1001     18756 18279  0 17:36 pts/6    00:00:00 grep doge
$ ps -ef | grep auro
1001     18522     1  0 17:24 ?        00:00:06 ./auroracoin-d/src/auroracoind
1001     18758 18279  0 17:36 pts/6    00:00:00 grep auro
$ ps -ef | grep anon
1001     18743 18279  3 17:35 pts/6    00:00:01 ./anoncoin-d/src/anoncoind
1001     18762 18279  0 17:36 pts/6    00:00:00 grep anon
```

Answer (score 5):

The sixth field indicates the terminal the command is running on.  In the case of your grep command, it is running on pts/6, or pseudo terminal number 6, which happens to be the pseudo terminal allocated to the terminal window you opened.  Daemons are not attached to any terminal; they just run in the background with no human interaction, hence the "?".